# .htaccess 301 redirect WHOLE WordPress site EXCEPT root domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have been searching around and I couldn't find the following.
I was wondering if it is possible to redirect my whole WordPress blog to a new domain except for the root or homepage itself.
Any push in the right direction would be great. I hope I'm not asking a silly question here!

Thanks in advance for anyone who has the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Wow. You are a wizard. It worked right off the bat!
Thanks so much!!